# Definition of a moment map with physical context

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, sg.symplectic-geometry, classical-mechanics, symmetry, moment-map

This was originally posted on Math Stack Exchange, but without an answer. I thus move it here, and hope it's not because I express it unclearly.

---

Suppose $(M,\omega)$ is a symplectic manifold ["well"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_map) acted by a Lie group $G$. Then we can define the moment map $\mu: M \to \frak{g}^*$ to be the dual of $H_\xi$, which is defined to be the integral (if exists) of the (dual of the) vector field induced by the infinitesimal action of $G$. This makes sense to me mathematically.

According to this [page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/moment+map#AngularMomentum), when $M$ is $T^*\mathbb{R}^3$ naturally acted by $SO(3)$, then the associated moment map reduces to the classical angular momentum (after choosing a suitable basis for $\frak{so}_3$). I also found an explicit calculation there. This makes sense to me physically.

What **does not make sense** to me is the passage from classical angular momentum to the modern definition of moment map. As pointed out in the last paragraph, the other side (modern->classical) can be easily obtained by choosing an ad-hoc basis. But from classical to modern is always harder. I wonder how they came up with the modern definition.

#### My guess

If I **guess** where it was from, I would start with Noether's theorem, which roughly says that *any physical dynamic system with symmetries has a conserved quantity*. Classical angular momentum is just one of the well-known conserved quantities. To unify all conserved quantities, people pinned down the axioms for the above to make sense, and defined the moment map to be a map that encodes a conversed quantity associate to a fixed symmetry.

#### Question

1. Is my guess correct?
2. If my guess is (closed to) correct, is there any text that develops the definition of moment maps in this vein?

Comment: This seems to be a pretty good answer concerning the history of the momentum map: https://mathoverflow.net/a/249174/17047

Comment: Possibly related remark: I believe that the comoment map is more natural. This is a Lie algebra morphism $\mathfrak{g}\to C^\infty(M)$. This is in bijection with the notion of moment map. I claim it's more natural on account of its image is exactly the conserved charges (in a physics context) and also this definition generalises directly to the case where you have an $L_\infty$-algebra of symmetries, see e.g. arxiv.org/abs/1304.2051

Answer (score 1):

$\def \cG {\cal G}$
$\def \RR {\mathbf R}$

The *moment map* is one of the most important constructions in symplectic mechanics. There are at least two main reasons for that:

1. The moment map $\mu : M \to \cG^*$ on a homogeneous symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$ under the action of a Lie group $G$ is a covering onto its image [Sou70]. That classifies what is called now *elementary systems*, or *elementary particles* when the group $G$ is the Galileo group (Galilean mechanics) or Poincaré group (for relativity). This is called the *theorem KKS* for Kirillov-Kostant-Souriau.
2. In the case of a **presymplectic** system $(M,\omega)$, that is:
   $$
    \dim\big(\ker (\omega) \big) = \mathrm{cst.}
   $$
   **Theorem** (Noether-Souriau) *The moment map $\mu$ is constant on the characteristics of $\omega$.*

This theorem is the generalisation in the context of symplectic dynamic of the classical Noether theorem since in the case of $\omega = d\lambda$ and $\lambda$ is given by a Lagrangian, it coincides with the Noether theorem.

The characteristics of $\omega$ are the integral sub-manifolds of the distribution of tangent subspaces
$$
x \mapsto \ker(\omega).
$$
In symplectic mechanics the *characteristics* of a presymplectic form are regarded as the solutions of the dynamical system characterised by $\omega$ on the space of initial conditions $M$. Hence, the values of $\mu$ are the conserved quantities associated with the action of $G$.

In the case of the Galileo group, represented by the matrices:
$$
g = 
\begin{pmatrix}
A & b & c\\
0 & 1 & e \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}   
\quad \text{with} \quad 
\begin{array}{l}
A \in \mathrm{SO}(3)  \\
b,c \in \RR^3 \\
e \in \RR.
\end{array} 
$$
Acting on $\RR^3 \times \RR^3 \times \RR$, the space of initial conditions of a free particle:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
A & b & c\\
0 & 1 & e \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}   
\begin{pmatrix}
r\\
t \\
 1
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
Ar + bt + c\\
t +e \\
 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The moment map is given by:
$$
\mu(r,v,t) = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
l = m r \times v & \text{the kinetic momentum relative to $A \in \mathrm{SO}(3)$}. \\
p = mv  & \text{the momentum relative to the boost $b \in \RR^3$. }
 \\
g = r - vt & \text{the center of mass relative to the displacement $c \in \RR^3$.}\\
E = {mv^2 \over 2} & \text{the kinetic energy relative to the time translation $e \in \RR$.}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
That gives the 10 components of the moment map in Galilean mechanics for the example of a free particle. Of course, this extends to any free Galilean mechanical system described by a presymplectic manifold invariant by the Galileo group. Actually this is the definition of a *free Galilean dynamical system* in symplectic mechanics.

**Note.** The moment map has been generalized in diffeology [PIZ10], and then the classification theorem above has been extended in to any symplectic manifold [DIZ22]:

**Theorem**. *Every connected symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$ is a coadjoint orbit of a central extension by the torus of periods $T_\omega$ of its group $\mathrm{Ham}(M,\omega)$ of Hamiltonian diffeomorphisms*.

---

References:

[Sou70] Jean-Marie Souriau. *Structure des Systèmes Dynamiques*, Dunod 1970.

[PIZ10] Patrick Iglesias-Zemmour. *The moment map in diffeology* (2010). Memoirs of the American Mathematical Society. Volume 207.

[DIZ22] Paul Donato & Patrick Iglesias-Zemmour. *Every symplectic manifold is a (linear) coadjoint orbit*. Canadian Mathematical Bulletin, Volume 65, Issue 2, June 2022, pp. 345 - 360.